# Disable the Div in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi Im having a dificulties to disabled the Div. when i scratch and make it 50% the 2 box must be disabled and cannot scratched it

here is the code

body

```
<div class="scratch-container">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
  <div id="promo" class="scratchpad"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
  <div id="promo2" class="scratchpad"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
  <div id="promo3" class="scratchpad"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-5">

     <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn">Reset page</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Java Script

```
scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
        if ((percent > 50)) {
          $('.promo2').prop('disabled',true);
          $('.promo3').prop('disabled',true);
        }
      }
```

**Full code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <style type="text/css">
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.scratchpad{
  width: 250px;
  height: 245px;
  border: solid 5px #FFFFFF;
  margin:0 auto;
}
body {
    background: red;
}
.scratch-container {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width:100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  .scratchpad {width:400px;height:396px;}
  .scratch-container {width:400px !important;}
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  .scratchpad {width:290px;height:287px;}
  .scratch-container {width:290px !important;}
}
.promo-container {
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    width:450px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial,Sans-serif;
    color:#333;
    font-size:16px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
.btn {
  background:#56CFD2;
  color:#FFF;
  padding:10px 25px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:15px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:600;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radiuss:3px;
}
.disabled{
  position:relative; 
  z-index:10;
  pointer-events:none
}
.disabled:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:100;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}

  </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: green;"> 
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-top: 250px">
    <div class="scratch-container">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="promo" class="scratchpad"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="promo2" class="scratchpad"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="promo3" class="scratchpad"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-5">

         <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn">Reset page</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/js/wScratchPad.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
    location.reload();
}

var promoCode = '';
var bg1 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/400.png';
var bg2 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/500.png';
var bg3 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/sorry.png';
var bgArray= [ bg1, bg2, bg3 ],
selectBG = bgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArray.length)];
if (selectBG == bg1) {
    promoCode = 'SCRATCH400';
  } else if (selectBG == bg2) {
    promoCode = 'SCRATCH500';
  } if (selectBG == bg3) {
    var promoCode = '';
  }
$('#promo').wScratchPad({
    // the size of the eraser
    size        : 80,     
    // the randomized scratch image   
    bg:  selectBG,
    // give real-time updates
    realtime    : true, 
    // The overlay image
    fg: 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/overlay.png',
    // The cursor (coin) image
    'cursor': 'url("https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/coin1.png") 5 5, default',

    scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
        if ((percent > 50)) {
          $('#promo2').prop('disabled',true);
          $('#promo3').prop('disabled',true);
        }
      }
 });

var bgs1 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/400.png';
var bgs2 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/500.png';
var bgs3 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/sorry.png';
var bgArrays= [ bgs1, bgs2, bgs3 ],
selectBGs = bgArrays[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArrays.length)];
if (selectBGs == bgs1) {
    promoCode = 'SCRATCH400';
  } else if (selectBGs == bgs2) {
    promoCode = 'SCRATCH500';
  } if (selectBGs == bgs3) {
    var promoCode = '';
  }
$('#promo2').wScratchPad({
    // the size of the eraser
    size        : 80,     
    // the randomized scratch image   
    bg:  selectBGs,
    // give real-time updates
    realtime    : true, 
    // The overlay image
    fg: 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/overlay.png',
    // The cursor (coin) image
    'cursor': 'url("https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/coin1.png") 5 5, default',

    scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
        if ((percent > 50)) {
          $('#promo').prop('disabled',true);
          $('#promo3').prop('disabled',true);
        }
      }
 });


var bgss1 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/400.png';
var bgss2 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/500.png';
var bgss3 = 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/sorry.png';
var bgArrayss= [ bgss1, bgss2, bgss3 ],
selectBGss = bgArrayss[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgArrayss.length)];
if (selectBGss == bgss1) {
    promoCode = 'SCRATCH400';
  } else if (selectBGss == bgss2) {
    promoCode = 'SCRATCH500';
  } if (selectBGss == bgss3) {
    var promoCode = '';
  }
$('#promo3').wScratchPad({
    // the size of the eraser
    size        : 80,     
    // the randomized scratch image   
    bg:  selectBGss,
    // give real-time updates
    realtime    : true, 
    // The overlay image
    fg: 'https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/overlay.png',
    // The cursor (coin) image
    'cursor': 'url("https://jennamolby.com/scratch-and-win/images/coin1.png") 5 5, default',

    scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
        if ((percent > 50)) {
$('#promo2').addClass('disabled');

    $('#promo3').addClass('disabled'); 

        }
      }
 });
</script>

</td></tr>  </table></form>
<audio id="audio" src="sounds/drum.mp3" ></audio>
</BODY></html>
```

Comment: `div` elements cannot be disabled. Only form elements.

Comment: You can disable them by css `pointer-events:none`

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi can you guide me how to use that.

Comment: First Thing - div cannot e disabled, you can only disable button or input elements.
Next thing - your calling a div with class  `('.promo1/2/3'), and you are using id attr, so it should be ('#promo1/2/3')`

If you are trying to block user from copying or clicking the div, you should instead define a class which wwill add a overlay over a div which disable click/copy.

Comment: @kumar what is the best to do so i cannot scatch the other box?

Comment: @JosephParagua check the following example ucreated using your code, check css / js code modified

`https://jsbin.com/yicubir/edit?html,css,js,console,output`

Answer (score 0):

Set the css `pointer-events` property to none like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#promo2, #promo3").css('pointer-events', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `disabled` in div. You can disable the scratchpad like this if needed. If this don't work you need to disable it in the function that does scratch.

Try this,

```
scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        /* Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched*/
        if ((percent > 50)) {
          $('#promo2').css('pointer-events','none');
          $('#promo3').css('pointer-events','none');
        }
      }
```

or

```
scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
        if ((percent > 50)) {
          /* Disable all other scratchpads except this, make sure you pass the event correctly*/

          $('.scratchpad').not($(e.target)).css('pointer-events','none');
        }
      }
```

**Update**

You code has not issues, I verified the original source. But you need to take care of below items to work properly.

1. The file should be run from a webserver
2. Load images and JS files (wScratchPad.min.js) from the same server to avoid canvas cross domain origin  issues
3. Change you code to below and it should work

   ```
            if ((percent > 50)) {
             $('#promo2').css('pointer-events','none');
             $('#promo3').css('pointer-events','none');
           }
   ```

Comment: Is that function calling correctly? put an alert/console and see the value of percent.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5r6fvvr67a0i2c/index.html?dl=0 - full code DL it is dropbox

Comment: alredy did that

Comment: i dont get it ahaha :((

Comment: Can you upload the file to https://jennamolby.com and check, it should work or share the link after uploading.

Comment: in that dropbox it should be html and it can use even not upload in that jennamolby.com

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML head tag file

```
<style type="text/CSS">.disabled , .disabled canvas{pointer-events:none!important;}</style>
```

In your JS

```
scratchMove: function (e, percent) {
        // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
        if ((percent > 50)) {
          $('#promo2,#promo3').addClass('disabled');
        }
      }
```

```js
/*! wScratchPad - v2.0.3 - 2014-04-05 */!function(a){"use strict";function b(b,c){this.$el=a(b),this.options=c,this.init=!1,this.enabled=!0,this._generate()}b.prototype={_generate:function(){return a.support.canvas?(this.canvas=document.createElement("canvas"),this.ctx=this.canvas.getContext("2d"),"static"===this.$el.css("position")&&this.$el.css("position","relative"),this.$img=a('<img src=""/>').attr("crossOrigin","").css({position:"absolute",width:"100%",height:"100%"}),this.$scratchpad=a(this.canvas).css({position:"absolute",width:"100%",height:"100%"}),this.$scratchpad.bindMobileEvents(),this.$scratchpad.mousedown(a.proxy(function(b){return this.enabled?(this.canvasOffset=a(this.canvas).offset(),this.scratch=!0,void this._scratchFunc(b,"Down")):!0},this)).mousemove(a.proxy(function(a){this.scratch&&this._scratchFunc(a,"Move")},this)).mouseup(a.proxy(function(a){this.scratch&&(this.scratch=!1,this._scratchFunc(a,"Up"))},this)),this._setOptions(),this.$el.append(this.$img).append(this.$scratchpad),this.init=!0,void this.reset()):(this.$el.append("Canvas is not supported in this browser."),!0)},reset:function(){var b=this,c=Math.ceil(this.$el.innerWidth()),d=Math.ceil(this.$el.innerHeight());this.pixels=c*d,this.$scratchpad.attr("width",c).attr("height",d),this.$img.hide(),this.options.bg&&("#"===this.options.bg.charAt(0)?this.$el.css("backgroundColor",this.options.bg):(this.$el.css("backgroundColor",""),this.$img.attr("src",this.options.bg))),this.options.fg&&("#"===this.options.fg.charAt(0)?(this.ctx.fillStyle=this.options.fg,this.ctx.beginPath(),this.ctx.rect(0,0,c,d),this.ctx.fill(),this.$img.show()):a(new Image).attr("src",this.options.fg).load(function(){b.ctx.drawImage(this,0,0,c,d),b.$img.show()}))},clear:function(){this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,Math.ceil(this.$el.innerWidth()),Math.ceil(this.$el.innerHeight()))},enable:function(a){this.enabled=a===!0?!0:!1},destroy:function(){this.$el.children().remove(),a.removeData(this.$el,"wScratchPad")},_setOptions:function(){var a,b;for(a in this.options)this.options[a]=this.$el.attr("data-"+a)||this.options[a],b="set"+a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substring(1),this[b]&&this[b](this.options[a])},setBg:function(){this.init&&this.reset()},setFg:function(){this.setBg()},setCursor:function(a){this.$el.css("cursor",a)},_scratchFunc:function(a,b){a.pageX=Math.floor(a.pageX-this.canvasOffset.left),a.pageY=Math.floor(a.pageY-this.canvasOffset.top),this["_scratch"+b](a),(this.options.realtime||"Up"===b)&&this.options["scratch"+b]&&this.options["scratch"+b].apply(this,[a,this._scratchPercent()])},_scratchPercent:function(){for(var a=0,b=this.ctx.getImageData(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height),c=0,d=b.data.length;d>c;c+=4)0===b.data[c]&&0===b.data[c+1]&&0===b.data[c+2]&&0===b.data[c+3]&&a++;return a/this.pixels*100},_scratchDown:function(a){this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out",this.ctx.lineJoin="round",this.ctx.lineCap="round",this.ctx.strokeStyle=this.options.color,this.ctx.lineWidth=this.options.size,this.ctx.beginPath(),this.ctx.arc(a.pageX,a.pageY,this.options.size/2,0,2*Math.PI,!0),this.ctx.closePath(),this.ctx.fill(),this.ctx.beginPath(),this.ctx.moveTo(a.pageX,a.pageY)},_scratchMove:function(a){this.ctx.lineTo(a.pageX,a.pageY),this.ctx.stroke()},_scratchUp:function(){this.ctx.closePath()}},a.support.canvas=document.createElement("canvas").getContext,a.fn.wScratchPad=function(c,d){function e(){var d=a.data(this,"wScratchPad");return d||(d=new b(this,a.extend(!0,{},c)),a.data(this,"wScratchPad",d)),d}if("string"==typeof c){var f,g=[],h=(void 0!==d?"set":"get")+c.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+c.substring(1),i=function(){f.options[c]&&(f.options[c]=d),f[h]&&f[h].apply(f,[d])},j=function(){return f[h]?f[h].apply(f,[d]):f.options[c]?f.options[c]:void 0},k=function(){f=a.data(this,"wScratchPad"),f&&(f[c]?f[c].apply(f,[d]):void 0!==d?i():g.push(j()))};return this.each(k),g.length?1===g.length?g[0]:g:this}return c=a.extend({},a.fn.wScratchPad.defaults,c),this.each(e)},a.fn.wScratchPad.defaults={size:5,bg:"#cacaca",fg:"#6699ff",realtime:!0,scratchDown:null,scratchUp:null,scratchMove:null,cursor:"crosshair"},a.fn.bindMobileEvents=function(){a(this).on("touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel",function(a){var b=a.changedTouches||a.originalEvent.targetTouches,c=b[0],d="";switch(a.type){case"touchstart":d="mousedown";break;case"touchmove":d="mousemove",a.preventDefault();break;case"touchend":d="mouseup";break;default:return}var e=document.createEvent("MouseEvent");e.initMouseEvent(d,!0,!0,window,1,c.screenX,c.screenY,c.clientX,c.clientY,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),c.target.dispatchEvent(e)})}}(jQuery);


$('#promo2').wScratchPad({
  size        : 5,          // The size of the brush/scratch.
  bg          : '#cacaca',  // Background (image path or hex color).
  fg          : '#6699ff',  // Foreground (image path or hex color).
  realtime    : true,       // Calculates percentage in realitime.
  scratchDown : null,       // Set scratchDown callback.
  scratchUp   : null,       // Set scratchUp callback.
  scratchMove :  function (e, percent) {
        // Show the plain-text promo code and call-to-action when the scratch area is 50% scratched
        if ((percent > 50)) {
          $('#promo1,#promo2').addClass('disabled');
        }
      },       // Set scratcMove callback.
  cursor      : 'crosshair' // Set cursor.
});
```

```css
.scratchpad{
height:50px;
width:50px}

.disabled , .disabled canvas{pointer-events:none!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="col-xs-4">
  <div id="promo2" class="scratchpad"></div>
    </div>

<script>

</script>
```

Comment: dropbox.com/s/j5r6fvvr67a0i2c/index.html?dl=0  here is my fullsource code @ramesh

Comment: Are you opening this file from a webserver? This looks like a cross origin issue.